# Unable to download complete Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

[image]

Hi,
I am trying to get the complete SDK. But one issue with the system in my office is few websites and ports are blocked. So everytime when it tries to get a list of the Android versions and Tools, it fails.
Get an error in Android SDK Manager Log as :

**Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused**

I tried to run android-studio-bundle-135.1629389.exe for Android Studio. I get an error as **"Unable to elevate ERROR : 1812"**.

Somehow i added Armeabi to SDK but still it lacks the tools needed to create and AVD since I get an error as "No CPU/ABI system image available for this target".

Is there a link where i can get the complete SDK ? Or series of steps that anyone can help me with to setup my Android SDK.

NOTE : I am using SDK with Eclipse Luna (downloaded the pack adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702 for Android developer site).

I am stuck and tried few other downloads but could not get it all working.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388746/failed-to-fetch-url-https-dl-ssl-google-com-android-repository-addons-list-1-x

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ask your IT Team to allow you access to that url. As it is your connections firewall that is blocking you from downloading the SDK.

Comment: I understand. But I want to install for RnD purpose. So just for installation i'll have to go through series of approvals which takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Firewall was Disabled and your antivirus and check out this link at #4th and #5th point
[ https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21359

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second part of your question:

> I tried to run android-studio-bundle-135.1629389.exe for Android
>   Studio. I get an error as "Unable to elevate ERROR : 1812".

I had this problem of the Android Studio setup being unable to elevate even tough I was running it as Administrator, and it came to a point where it wasn't even showing an error number anymore. It only solved when I deleted all my files on my temp folder, as easy as that. To find where your temp folder is, just open windows explorer and type %temp% at the address bar, then delete everything that is not saying it's being used by another software, if it asks you to.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your proxy settings if u are using proxy to connect to internet in 
C:\Users{USERNAME}.AndroidStudio\config\options.other.xml

```
<component name="HttpConfigurable">
   <option name="USE_HTTP_PROXY" value="true" />
   <option name="PROXY_HOST" value="11.160.0.212" />
   <option name="PROXY_PORT" value="8080" />
</component>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem bit is solved

try with "Run astried with "Run as administrator" administrator"