# SDK Manager unable to fetch content - Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

My Android SDK manager starts and then tries to fetch new updates. But it can't fetch content and shows following error in log window:

> Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml,
>   reason: Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused

I am using windows 7 32-bit and working with Eclipse ADT.

Comment: a self-answered question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Solutions:

1. Starting SDK manager as Administrator

[image]

2. Starting android.bat from command-line.

[image]

3. Updating Eclipse ADT from `help/check for updates`.

[image]

4. Disabling windows firewall from `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Customize Settings`

[image]

5. Clearing download catche from tools/options in SDK Manager.

[image]

6. Adding Google's repository website in use-defined site from `tools/Manage Add-on sites` in SDK Manager.
   [image]
7. Forcing https// sources to be fetched using http:// in SDK Manager

[image]

8. If **any of above solution does not work** then the last solution
   remained is to **disable firewall of your antivirus**.

Some antivirus packages like Avast contains their own firewalls that blocks fetching content in SDK manager. You must have to disable antivirus firewall from its settings.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux check that the cache directory exists:

```
mkdir -p ~/.android/cache
```

and that you have rights to it:

```
ls -ld ~/.android/cache/
drwxr-xr-x 2 YOU YOU 4096 lis 24 13:33 /home/YOU/.android/cache/
```