# Ionic build android failed - Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'

Tags: sdk, push-notification, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm added **phonegap-plugin-push** (http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch) to my project, then after I'm build/run it, the error was appeared. [image: error console]

I've try so many ways (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-service-push-client/issues/22)
([SDK Manager unable to fetch content - Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388746/sdk-manager-unable-to-fetch-content-connection-to-https-dl-ssl-google-com-re)), but nothing can help me.

Before I'm added this plugin, my project was fine.

Comment: Did you try the things the error suggests?

Comment: yup, but it got same errors.

Answer (score -1):

You can setting file project.properties on yourApp\platforms\android

You can edit `cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v13:23+` to your support version