# Android Studio component installation not working in proxy security server

Tags: android, performance

Following message show when trying to open android studio.

Android SDK was installed to C:\Users\atiq\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1
  Refresh Sources
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: Connect Connection timed out: connect
Refresh Sources:
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: Connect Connection timed out: connect
There is nothing to install or update.
The following SDK component was not installed: build-tools-21.1.1

Comment: Do you connected to the internet? Gradle requires internet to build the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create or modify file: ~/.AndroidStudio/config/options/other.xml or ~/.AndroidStudioBeta/config/options/other.xml depending on Android Studio version.

See in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27636195/1208793
or https://plus.google.com/110705866902383848310/posts/THYjBYu3Uh5

For using pac file for proxy settings I did this:

```
<option name="USE_HTTP_PROXY" value="false" />
<option name="USE_PROXY_PAC" value="true" />
<option name="PROXY_HOST" value="proxy.x.com:81/mypac.pac" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the file:  ~/.AndroidStudio/config/options/other.xml

For the proxy settings use :

```
<component name="HttpConfigurable">
<option name="PROXY_TYPE_IS_SOCKS" value="false" />
<option name="USE_HTTP_PROXY" value="true" />
<option name="USE_PROXY_PAC" value="false" />
<option name="PROXY_HOST" value="****Proxy Used*****" />
<option name="PROXY_PORT" value="8080" />
<option name="PROXY_AUTHENTICATION" value="true" />
<option name="PROXY_LOGIN" value="*****Your username*****" />
<option name="PROXY_PASSWORD_CRYPT" value="*****Your password" />
<option name="KEEP_PROXY_PASSWORD" value="true" />
<option name="myGenericPasswords">
  <map />
</option>
<option name="myGenericCancelled">
  <set />
</option>
<option name="PROXY_EXCEPTIONS" value="true" />
<option name="USE_PAC_URL" value="false" />
<option name="PAC_URL" value="" />
```